# Bar chart with individual legend aligned to each bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I need help to create a figure of a stacked bar chart for a Springer article. I am quite new to Latex, and although I have worked out how to create a stacked bar by checking previous questions, but I cannot find any example suiting the specifications I need.
Numeric values for y axis should be invisible and y axis should be a dotted line.
Legend should indicate the species name for each bar.
I have attached an image to illustrate how the chart should look. 
[image]
What would be the correct approach to get legends looking like that? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As a new member, it is recommended to visit these pages https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour to be informed and also to know about Minimal Example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Otherwise, more specifically to your question: Could you show us what you succeed to achieve until now ? It will be useful to help you properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with the `pgfplots` package. Hiding the ticks on the y axis can be done with `ymajorticks = false`. Having a dotted (or dashed) line can be done with appending the style for the `inner y axis line`. Please note that it would be the `outer` line in case you were to use an y axis that would not have the value `middle` (but `left`, i.e. no negative y values). Lastly, `nodes near coords` can be used to display the species' names beside their values, or any other text-based meta data. For this, enable `nodes near coords, point meta = explicit symbolic` (the default option for `nodes near coords` would be to just display the measured value).

(Btw, the image you have supplied does not show a stacked bar chart. It's just a normal bar chart)

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            xmin = -.5,
            axis lines* = middle,
            ymajorticks = false,
            every inner y axis line/.append style = {dashed},
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style = {anchor = west,font = \itshape},
            point meta = explicit symbolic,
            xtick = {-0.5,0,0.5,...,3.5},
            xlabel = {$RS = \log (LC_{50Lf}/LC_{50i})$}
            ]
            \addplot [fill=black!70] coordinates {
            (3.75,1) [V. c. cochienis]
            (2.75,2) [L. teres]         
            (2.50,3) [L. s. claibornensis]
            (2.40,4) [A. pectorosa]
            (2.40,5) [L. subviridis]
            (2.30,6) [U. imbecillis]            
            (0.50,7) [C. rhizophorae]
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! I only have one more question I did not think of at the time. In the case of having bars on the negative values side, how can I force the nodes near coords to be anchor=east just for those cases. As per the previous example, lets say 'L. teres' coordenate is (-2.75). I looked into other previous questions and saw it is posible to use \ifnum, but I am struggling to understand how to use it...Could I ask for a bit of extra help? Thanks again!!!